# Repeating watermark text

Tags: c#, pdf, watermark

I'm using PDF4NET to draw watermark on a pdf pages. Now I want to repeat the watermark text all over the page in tile mode. Something like this [watermark](https://watermarkly.com/blog/tile-mode/).

Below is what I do to repeat the watermark text:

```
var text= string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Sample   ", 800));
PDFTextFormatOptions format= new PDFTextFormatOptions();
format.Align = PDFTextAlign.TopLeft;
// ----- 
// ....
page.Canvas.DrawTextBox(text, fontText, null, redBrush, 0, 0, page.Width, page.Height, format);
```

[image]
How can I make the text shown in tile mode regardless of the font size and length of text?

Comment: You can look up samples/documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/o2solutions/pdf4net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected layout cannot be generated automatically.
The code below shows a possible way to get the layout you need. You can play with X, Y to adjust the output as needed.

```
PDFFixedDocument document = new PDFFixedDocument();
PDFPage page = document.Pages.Add();

PDFBrush lightGrayBrush = new PDFBrush(PDFRgbColor.LightGray);
PDFStandardFont helvetica = new PDFStandardFont(PDFStandardFontFace.Helvetica, 12);
string watermarkText = "Sample Watermark";
double watermarkTextWidth = PDFTextEngine.MeasureString(watermarkText, helvetica).Width;

double y = 0;
double startX = watermarkTextWidth / 2;
int sign = -1;
while (y < page.Height)
{
    double x = startX;

    while (x < page.Width)
    {
        page.Canvas.DrawString(watermarkText, helvetica, lightGrayBrush, x, y);
        x = x + watermarkTextWidth + watermarkTextWidth / 4;
    }

    startX = startX + sign * watermarkTextWidth / 2;
    sign = -sign;

    y = y + 2 * helvetica.Size;
}

document.Save("InterleavedWatermak.pdf");
```

The output document is below:

[image: Interleaved watermark created with PDF4NET]

Disclaimer: I work for the company that develops the [PDF4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/features.htm) library.

Answer (score -1):

*You can use imagemagick:*

```
magick convert input.jpg -alpha set ( -background none -fill #fff7 -pointsize 16 label:Watermark -rotate -45 +repage +write mpr:tile +delete ) ( -clone 0 -resize 300% -colorize 100 -tile mpr:tile -draw "color 0,0 reset" -rotate 45 -chop 50%x50% ) -compose over -composite output.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: Note that for Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert.

Comment: The question is about *watermark on a **pdf***, not on some **jpg**.

Comment: Just as an example and reference